# Django foreign key relationship in model.py problem

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and don´t know how to solve the problem (google and stack didnt "helped"/i dont get it).

This is what I want to have as output:
[image]

Function.py

```
def test():
....
return(author, title, view....)
```

Models.py

```
class Pers(models.Model):
author = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Title(models.Model):
authors = models.ForeignKey('Pers', on.delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
view = models.CharField(max_length=10) 

p = test()
t = Pers(author = p[0])
t.save()

z = test()
y = Title(authors = z[0], title = z[1], view = z[2]
y.save()
```

My function (*Function.py*) works fine but I have problems with the databank. I can fill the *Pers*-table with "`DJ ES`" but I want to have it just one time (`ID[0] = DJ ES`, `ID[1] = MAX VA`, and so on). With my table I get multiply `DJ ES` (`ID[0] = DJ ES`, `ID[1] = DJ ES`, `ID[2] = DJ ES`, ...).

And I am not able to save `DJ ES` to my *Title*-table.
My latest error: `ValueError: Cannot assign "'DJ ES'": "Title.authors" must be a "Pers" instance.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django if you have a ForeignKey relationships, in your case authors is an instance of persons, so if you wanna create a Title you need to get the instance of person first:
`person = Pers.objects.get(pk=.. or author=..)` and then `Title(authors=person, ...)`

Comment: Thanks, but that sadly didnt helped me. Could you plz go a bit in detail?

Comment: I dont know what are you doing inside the test method but, if you create a person `t = Person(author = "DJ ES")` and save it `t.save()`. Then you can get the instance `person = Person.objects.get(author='DJ ES')` and make your `title = Title(authors=person, title='SONG 1', view=455)`, and `title.save()`

Answer (score 0):

Changed 'Pers' to Pers without single quote. like

`authors = models.ForeignKey(Pers, on.delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: At first try the simplest version of your code, for DEBUGING purpose, hopefull that may helps.